# How come piping yes to a file doesn't work?

Tags: linux, pipe

I tried doing this:

```
yes > yes.txt
```

Afterwards, yes.txt is created but is completely empty.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on OS X (BSD). Can you `yes | cat -v > yes.txt`, maybe your yes implementation `yes` somehow prevents writing into a file?

Comment: Also, you want to ask this on StackOverflow, I think.

Comment: @tekknolagi They'll just close it as off-topic. It's perfectly acceptable here.

Comment: @DanielBeck okey doke

Comment: Okay @RazorStorm the command doesn't finish, but my solution is correct. It's not *advisable* to do this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? "yes" command produces infinite number of lines consisting "y". If you just try to fill up your filesystem then there are more effective commands for that. For example **dd if=/dev/null of=yes.txt**

Comment: The source code to GNU `yes` does not indicate special handling of output to files. Are you sure that e.g. your disk isn't already full? Have you canceled the command, so e.g. buffering of writes to disk is no longer an issue?

Comment: Does your `yes` command work without redirection? Does it work when piped to another program (such as `yes | more`)? What does `yes --version` output?

Comment: On Windows, I was able to redirect to a file using the version of `yes` supplied with MinGW MSYS, producing a file several hundred megabytes in size within seconds.  Is your shell able to redirect standard output to a file?

Comment: @Cougar, `dd if=/dev/null of=yes.txt` does not write any actual data to the file; it would only truncate the file, since reading from `/dev/null` returns an EOF.  Replace `/dev/null` with `/dev/zero`.

Comment: @DragonLord, you are absolutely right here. I was probably too tired but that is not an excuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution; my harddrive was full >.<

Comment: If this was true, you should have received a `No space left on device` error.

Comment: @Gryllida, remove some files and try again.

at first I got a diskquota exceeded error while doing something else. I thought deleting the file would help, but the file didnt actually get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

you want to do

```
`yes` > yes.txt
```

Which will execute `yes` and write the output to `yes.txt`

---

Note: `yes` command outputs a line, 'y' by default, endlessly - the abovementioned process will consume memory, cpu, and disk space until there is no free memory, after which it gets terminated. You may have to terminate it manually.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? ` `yes` ` will never finish, it'll just consume lots of memory!

Comment: @DanielBeck that's what he wants... I did try it, in fact. He never asked if it was advisable :P

Comment: @DanielBeck see @ ChrisNava's answer, and @ RazorStorm's reply

Comment: On my system `Ctrl-C` was unable to cancel this answer's approach, but worked fine with the OP's non-working variant that actually worked for me. It might make the difference here ;-)

Comment: @DanielBeck ...what? and I had to kill the process manually

Comment: please make sure you know what `` or $() does before using that. @Daniel is right that only thing it does is a big memory consumption and termination after there is no free memory any more.

Comment: I agree with tekknolagi.  If the OP wants to jump off a cliff, let it be.

Comment: Thank you @Gryllida for editing (I went to bed) but can I have my upvote back please?

Comment: @RazorStorm I know it won't "kill" in the conventional sense, but it should bring it to a screeching halt.

Comment: @RazorStorm feel free to accept maybe? :P

Comment: +1 for a helpful answer, however the actual problem was my harddrive was full. hahahahahha

Comment: @RazorStorm no problem

Answer (score 1):

your original solution 
`yes > yes.txt` should work ... 
although you could work around it like this

```
while true; do echo yes; done >> yes.txt
```